# I am getting java IO exception while installing Hadoop 3.x on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

After doing all the required configuration, i am doing 'format the node name' and running the command "**bin/hdfs namenode -format**", but getting the below java IO exception:

I am following the below steps:
http://data-flair.training/blogs/installation-hadoop-3-x-ubuntu-pseudo-distributed-mode/

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /home/dataflair/hdata/dfs/name/current
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1704)
2017-09-08 09:59:40,098 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /home/dataflair/hdata/dfs/name/current
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1704)
2017-09-08 09:59:40,100 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-09-08 09:59:40,102 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at amit-virtual-machine/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Do you have permissions to create that directory?

Comment: Yes i have @tk421

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct path for **hadoop.tmp.dir** property in $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/**core-site.xml**.

```
<configuration> 
<property> 
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property> 
<property> 
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
<value>/home/{your ubuntu's user not dataflair}/hdata</value>
</property> 
</configuration>
```